# The `siunitx` package uses the wrong font for the micro symbol with babel

Tags: babel, siunitx

I use `babel` to write documents in my native language Hebrew. I also use the `siunitx` package to format numbers and units. I use custom fonts for Hebrew and English (for Hebrew since I need a font that supports the language, and for English simply because of style preferences). It seems that using the `\micro` command or any other command involving the mu symbol uses the Hebrew font I selected which doesn't have a mu symbol:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=tabular]{babel}

\babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

% Font setup
\babelfont{rm}{TeX Gyre Bonum}
\babelfont{sf}{TeX Gyre Adventor}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{David CLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{Miriam CLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{tt}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{Miriam Mono CLM}

\babelfont{david}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{David CLM}

\sisetup{
    group-separator = {,},
    group-digits=integer,
    uncertainty-mode=separate,
}

\begin{document}
\[ \SI{5}{\micro\meter} \]
\end{document}
```

This code produces

[image]

Which is wrong. If I use `\selectlanguage{english}` to switch to English, it uses the **custom** English font, which has a mu symbol, but it's different than the normal font which makes it look weird when combined with other symbols like micrometer:

[image]

How can I make `siunitx` use the default math font for the micro symbol? I tried to use the options `math-micro` and `text-micro` to change the symbol, but it seems these options no longer exist in `siunitx`.

Answer (score 4):

In v3, the standard setting for `\micro` uses `\textmu` for 8-bit engines and the literal character `μ` in text mode for Unicode engines: this is the safest choice in most cases. However, it's impossible to predict all font combinations, particularly with system font use. In the current case, neither `\textmu` nor the literal character is set up for the font in use. You will therefore need to re-define `\micro` to use whatever symbol you feel is most appropriate: by the look of things

```latex
\DeclareSIPrefix\micro{\ensuremath{\upmu}}{-6}
```

Comment: Interesting. I will try this later. However, the examples I provided use display math mode (`\[ … /]`). So why doesn’t it work properly there?